# What does 灒油 mean if no oil spatters or scatters?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I screen-shot [0:57](https://youtu.be/WCxzP9cvmWk?t=58). I don't understand how [灒](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%81%92) makes sense here. The chef heated oil, then poured on the 薑葱茸. No oil 灒!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is typical "borrowing" (假借)。 The chef did not know the word for "accumulating of oil" (neither do I), so he used "accumulating of water" - 灒 to describe the phenomenon of accumulating the oil by pouring the hot oil into the container.  He could have used 浇 which is a traditional Chinese cooking technique (typical way to spread hot oil on dried chilly flakes to make chilly paste/oil, and many other dishes), but it must apply with bigger and flatter container such as a plate.  灒 is the closest one.

Answer (score 1):

> 灒

1. spatter, splash
2. to scatter

When a chef stir-frying a dish, he would pour wine into the wok at the end to add aroma to the food. This action is never slow and gentle but always a quick sprinkle/ pour (灑/澆).

*You would see flames in the wok if the temperature of the wok is very high. We call that 鑊氣 in Cantonese*

When you pour liquid in a quick motion, the liquid would scatters on the surface it was poured onto, Therefore 灒 is used for 'to pour (in a quick motion)" as its extended meaning

Also, when boiling oil is poured on food, it sizzle and spatter

Another word we use for 'to pour' in Cantonese is [淋](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/254/) which can be a gentle or quick-motion pour